# Multiple bookdown/rmarkdown/knitr issues around kable-tables

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, bookdown

In RStudio I'm trying to use rmarkdown in conjunction with [bookdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/) (mostly for the capabilitites to reference tables and figures) and am running into trouble with the formatting in tables and captions. Please consider the following example:

````
---
title: "Test"
knit: "bookdown::render_book"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    keep_tex: yes
link-citations: true
references:
- type: article-journal
  id: WatsonCrick1953
  author:
  - family: Watson
    given: J. D.
  - family: Crick
    given: F. H. C.
  issued:
    1953
  title: 'Molecular structure of nucleic acids: a structure for     deoxyribose
nucleic acid'
  container-title: Nature
  volume: 171
  issue: 4356
  page: 737-738
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
@WatsonCrick1953
```{r test-table, tidy=FALSE, echo = FALSE}
kable(
  data.frame(
    Citation = c("@WatsonCrick1953"),
    Formatted.String = c("Some--Thing^2^")),
  caption = "*Bold* in a caption;"#, booktabs = TRUE
)
```
````

A detail of the resulting product is:
[image]

This has multiple issues:

1. "Bold" in the caption isn't rmarkdown formatted
2. "^2^" does not produce the expected superscripting (particularly strange, as "--" is understood as en-dash)
3. The citation is not understood within the table (in the text, above the table code, it works just fine but is not included in the screen shot)

A further issue is that the currently produced latex does not produce a reference to the "booktabs" package, which is presumably needed to properly use the "booktabs = TRUE" argument to kable (which comes directly from the booktabs documentation and thus ought to work).

Please let me know how I may achieve what I am trying ...

Joh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to `pander` does the trick:

````
---
title: "Test"
knit: "bookdown::render_book"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    keep_tex: yes
link-citations: true
references:
- type: article-journal
  id: WatsonCrick1953
  author:
  - family: Watson
    given: J. D.
  - family: Crick
    given: F. H. C.
  issued:
    1953
  title: 'Molecular structure of nucleic acids: a structure for deoxyribose nucleic acid'
  container-title: Nature
  volume: 171
  issue: 4356
  page: 737-738
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(pander)
```
@WatsonCrick1953
```{r test-table, tidy=FALSE, echo = FALSE}
pander(
  data.frame(
  Citation = c("@WatsonCrick1953"),
  Formatted.String = c("Some--Thing^2^")),
  caption = "*Not bold* in a caption; **bold** in a caption;",
  style = "simple",
  justify = "left"
)
```
````

Here's the result:
[image: Pander result]

1. Caption formatting is markdowny.
2. "^2^" etc. is properly understood.
3. Citing works just fine.

Comment: would you also have some recommendations for the following Qs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60058692/table-in-bookdown-huskydown-with-several-features-citation-caption-url-png-f/60058693#60058693? many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are knitting to a PDF, the output of `kable()` will automatically detect this, and be formatted to produce latex.

Thus you need to use latex instructions to format your text.

Try this:

1. set the chunk option to `results = 'asis'`
2. use `\\textbf{}` to produce bold

For example:

````
```{r test-table, tidy=FALSE, echo = FALSE, results='asis'}
library(knitr)
kable(
  data.frame(
    Citation = c("@WatsonCrick1953"),
    Formatted.String = c("Some--Thing^2^")),
  caption = "\\textbf{Bold} in a caption -- ;"

)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The "\\textbf{}" bit works indeed, albeit at the cost of portability (no html), which is annoying. However, the table-internal formatting (both the superscripting and the reference) do NOT work in the context of bookdown ...

Comment: As proposed [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211638), ` header-includes: - \usepackage{booktabs}` solves the booktabs issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was glad to find this post, although I just could not replicate Andrie's answer. I would like to add **that it is also possible** to have the table referenced using `pander` by modifying the caption as such: `caption = "(\\#tab:test-table) *Not bold* in a caption; **bold** in a caption;",`

I modified the code to produce an article pdf document rather than a book and this code works for me:

````
---
title: "Test"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    keep_tex: yes
link-citations: true
references:
- type: article-journal
  id: WatsonCrick1953
  author:
  - family: Watson
    given: J. D.
  - family: Crick
    given: F. H. C.
  issued:
    1953
  title: 'Molecular structure of nucleic acids: a structure for deoxyribose nucleic acid'
  container-title: Nature
  volume: 171
  issue: 4356
  page: 737-738
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(pander)
```

@WatsonCrick1953 in Table \@ref(tab:test-table)

```{r test-table, tidy=FALSE, echo = FALSE}
pander(
  data.frame(
  Citation = c("@WatsonCrick1953"),
  Formatted.String = c("Some--Thing^2^")),
  caption = "(\\#tab:test-table) *Not bold* in a caption; **bold** in a caption;",
  style = "simple",
  justify = "left"
)
```
````